# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Sidekiq worker when I save object. I don't use rails callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Sidekiq worker when I save object. I don't use rails callbacks.

I run worker from service, and save object in this service.

```
class LeadSmsSendingService < Rectify::Command
  ...initialize params

  def send_sms_message
    sms_conversation = lead.sms_conversations.find_or_create_by(sms_number: sms_number)
    attrs            = sms_form.to_hash.symbolize_keys.slice(:body, :direction, :from, :to)
                               .merge(campaign_id: campaign_id)
    sms_message      = sms_conversation.sms_messages.build(attrs)
    sms_message.to ||= lead.phone
    sms_message.body = VariableReplacement.new(lead).render(sms_message.body)

    # @todo we need to raise an exception here
    return unless sms_message.save

    DeliverSmsMessageWorker.perform_in(3.seconds, sms_message.id, 'LeadSmsSendingService')
  end
end

class DeliverSmsMessageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'priority'

  def perform(sms_message_id, from_where="Unknown")
    sms_message = SmsMessage.find(sms_message_id)

    sms_message.deliver!
  rescue StandardError => e
    Bugsnag.notify(e) do |report|
      # Add information to this report
      report.add_tab(:worker, { from_where: from_where.to_s })
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `SmsMessage.find(sms_message_id)` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if there is no record in `SmsMessage` with `id` == `sms_message_id`. Not sure what callbacks have to do with your question.

Comment: @anothermh I checked, the record there in the database.

Comment: Technically, you also checked by calling `SmsMessage.find(sms_message_id)` and that said the record is **not** in the database. It doesn't matter if you checked after the fact and found it in the database; your code raised an exception at runtime when it couldn't find it in the database, which means it isn't there when it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the record has still to be commited, even if it sounds strange because of the 3 seconds delay. Does it work if you increase this delay?

This link could be useful: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345